# Set an icon on a Vaadin Flow Tab

Tags: vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 8 you could set an icon on a `Tab` (of `TabSheet`):

```
tab#setIcon(...)
```

In Vaadin Flow (currently using 14.1) i cannot figure out how to set an icon in a `Tab` (of `Tabs`). It is not part of the API?!

---

**Update** based on answer Steffen Harbich.

```
Tabs#add(new HorizontalLayout(icon, new Text(text)));
```

However, the result is visually not very appealing and needs some tweaking.

[image]

**Second update** There is a better way to do this, and this one looks great!

```
Tab t = tabs.add("Help", () -> { ... });
t.addComponentAsFirst(VaadinIcon.QUESTION_CIRCLE_O.create());
```

[image]

This [is consistent](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-menu-bar/java-examples/items) with the way an icon is set on a `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible. Use the constructor `new Tab(Components...)` or add your icon using `Tab#add(Component...)`. The components will be shown in header of tab. For example, you could pass a `HorizontalLayout` that contains an icon and a text component.

Have a look at [this Vaadin tab component demo](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-tabs/java-examples), paragraph "Tabs with custom content".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. See my update. Conclusion is correct?

Comment: @rmuller There's no direct support like `setIcon` but IMO this is fine because you have full flexibility over content of tab header.